# QuestDB : difference between table_columns() and tables()

Tags: questdb

I am new to questdb.
To check if tables contain designated timestamp column we can either use tables() or table_columns(). If this is the case then what is the difference between both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To query column you can use either

```
table_columns('pos')

or

SHOW COLUMNS FROM 'mytable'
```

`tables()` does not show all the columns but lists all the tables.